# How to correctly add average, standard deviation and jitter in geom_plot()? ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am trying to create a graph that shows the mean, standard deviation and the dots of each value (jitter). However, I was unable to insert the average point and the standard deviations are the same for all categories (and this is incorrect).

**My code (example):**

```
# Package
library(ggplot2)

# Dataframe
fruit <- c()
value <- c()
for (i in 0:30) {
  list_fruit <- c('Apple','Banana','Pear')
  fruit <- append(fruit, sample(list_fruit, 1))
  value <-  append(value, sample(1:50, 1))
}
df <- data.frame(fruit, value)

# Seed
set.seed(123)

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = fruit, y = value, color = fruit)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = mean(value)-sd(value), ymax = mean(value)+sd(value)), col = 'black') +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue','purple'))
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the manual you're referring to uses an old version of ggplot2 which didn't allow for alternate orientations of data. For example `fun.y` is now called `fun`. Below an example as per ggplot2 version 3.3.3.

```r
# Package
library(ggplot2)

# Dataframe
fruit <- c()
value <- c()
for (i in 0:30) {
  list_fruit <- c('Apple','Banana','Pear')
  fruit <- append(fruit, sample(list_fruit, 1))
  value <-  append(value, sample(1:50, 1))
}
df <- data.frame(fruit, value)

# Seed
set.seed(123)

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = fruit, y = value, color = fruit)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) + 
  stat_summary(
    geom = "linerange",
    fun.data = mean_sdl, 
    fun.args = list(mult = 1),
    colour = "black"
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "point",
    fun = mean,
    colour = "black", size = 3
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue','purple'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>